# how to change background color of current page number of category listing pagination, magento2

Tags: magento2

I am using magento2. I want to know how to change background color of currently activated page number category listing pagination using admin panel. Is there any option to set background or I have to set it manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use css to do that, I think there is no way you can do it in Admin panel.